# Can both ends of WebRTC specify iceTransportPolicy as "relay" for same one turn server?

Tags: webrtc, turn

Assuming `Alice` and `Bob` are using WebRTC to establish a connection, and there is a TURN server available.

Both `Alice` and `Bob` set their `iceServers` to this server and also set the `iceTransportPolicy` as "relay".

Strangely, I am unable to establish a connection between the two. My turn server is Coturn. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question is easy: yes, both (and should) set the policy to `relay` if that's what you want to enforce.

The second question, why does it not work, is difficult to answer without more detail. Perhaps the better question is how to debug this, so that's how I'll try to help. I usually do this by printing all returned candidates to the console of type `relay`. If either side does not receive any such candidates, then you have a smoking gun (often an authentication issue with coturn).

The other helpful tool is the telnet CLI coturn has (see the `/etc/turnserver.conf` file for details). Activate that, log in, and use `ps` to show all current sessions. You should find two active sessions, one for each side.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll investigate it and ask another question about the problem.

Comment: Hi, would you please help me to review this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303280 thank you very much!